# Screen management: How to switch between screens

Tags: java, libgdx, screen, menu

How can I switch between different screens that implement `Screen`?

Comment: Draw the background then the buttons. Check if mouse clicked position was inside a  button's rectangle (x, y, width, height).

Comment: and then? that is just checking if the condition is true.

Comment: That is what a menu is. The behavior after a button was clicked depends on your game and is for you to implement. All you need is a way to idenify which button was clicked and I explained briefly that you can check for `Point (mouse position) inside Rectangle (button bounds)`. It is like asking what will happen if I press "q" in a game. In one game you might use a spell, in another you might quit the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below. Off course you need to add the Button to the stage, create a skin and the OptionScreen yourself.

```
@Override
    public void show() {
        final OptionScreen optionScreen = new OptionScreen();

        TextButton optionButton = new TextButton("Options", skin);

        optionButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(optionScreen);
            }
        });        
    }
```

Because we use `optionScreen` inside a listener here it has to be final since the application never knows when the button is clicked it. You can also just create a `new` instance of `OptionScreen` inline `setScreen(new OptionScreen);`.